# Rails Action Mailer with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I understand this has been asked before and I've been following Rails ActionMailer Guides as well as looking through a few related questions on stackoverflow. I'm running a localhost and trying to send emails from there. From the rails guides, I followed every step and double checked everything is written as in the guides. I've also read a few questions found here, but still my emails aren't sending from localhost. Also, I'm not getting any errors within my server.

config/environments/development.rb

**EDIT**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }

  #Mailers
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'dogseeker7@gmail.com'}

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'localhost:3000',
    user_name:            ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"],                                                                                                                   
    password:             ENV["DOG_SEEKER_GMAIL"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

mailers/admin_mailer.rb

```
Class AdminMailer < Devise::Mailer
helper :application
include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
```

**Edit**

```
def welcome_email(admin)                                                                                                                                
    @admin = admin
    @login_url = "localhost:3000/admins/sign_in"
    mail(to: @admin.email, subject: "Welcome to Dog Seeker!")
end
```

app/admin/admin_controllers.rb

```
def create
   @admin = Admin.new(params[:admin])

   respond_to do |format|
     if @admin.save
       AdminMailer.welcome_email(@admin).deliver_now
       format.html { redirect_to(@admin, notice: 'Admin was successfully created.') }
       format.json { render json: @admin, status: :created, location: @admin }
     else
       format.html { redirect_to new_admin_registration_path }
       format.json { render json: @admin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

**UPDATE**

Log when new admin Signs Up

```
Started POST "/admins" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-05 22:09:15 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<token>==", "admin"=>{"email"=>"stenglinephoto@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Admin Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "stenglinephoto@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "admins" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "stenglinephoto@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "<password>"], ["created_at", "2017-08-06 05:09:15.904920"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-06 05:09:15.904920"]]
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "admins" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "last_sign_in_ip" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "admins"."id" = $7  [["sign_in_count", 1], ["current_sign_in_at", "2017-08-06 05:09:15.909337"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2017-08-06 05:09:15.909337"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-06 05:09:15.909955"], ["id", 29]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 172ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-05 22:09:15 -0700
Processing by HomepagesController#index as HTML
  Rendering homepages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered homepages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Admin Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 29], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (5.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_main.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 16.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

**Another update**

I have another mailer that gets sent when a dog is created and that works fine from localhost and with all the above configurations. My guess is the reason that mailers won't send when an admin account is created is due to the devise registrations controller overriding my controller. In other words, it's not hitting my create action in the admin_controller, but is hitting the registration within devises registration controller.

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: From my past use of ActionMailer, I don't believe the email will get sent through development. Look at your logs and you should see the email there.

Comment: I think it should go. We need the logs to see how things are triggered. However, I would recommend using Mailhog or mailcatcher (the latest is a gem & both are available in Docker so they don't mess up your environment).

Comment: There is something that drew my attention in your code above `@login_url = "https://dogseeker.herokuapp.com/admins/sign_in"` while you actually are defining the url of your dev environment to be `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
`. So I do not get if your question is for a development or production (test or staging) environment.

Comment: Hey Stephane, thanks for looking. To clarify, my app is currently in development. When I deploy to production, that will be the URL. Would the @login_url be different when I'm in the development?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but during dev you should point to dev URLs and during staging, to staging URLs and so on. That way you make sure that dev, test, (staging) and production are separated and you don't mix up things. One point. Sending emails with Google has limitation (number of emails sent, etc.) You can find pretty good alternatives with free plans (such as www.sparkpost.com). Can you share the log of your app?

Comment: You configuration of actionmailer lools good. Just one question: `DOG_SEEKER_GMAIL` is the password (as an ENV variable) correct?

Comment: Quick update, just checked the logs and there isn't any mention about an email being sent, or anything about email in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to follow the guide from [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users) and was able to make it work when admins sign up.

Comment: +1. Thanks Kyle. Implementing confirmable user accounts helped me as well. I had the exact same problem. I'm sure the bug with welcome email is still there because welcome email is not confirmation email. Please let me know if eventually you figured out what was wrong with the welcome email.

Comment: Hey @inmydelorean, it’s been a while since I looked at the code, but I do remember getting confirmation emails working. You’re welcome to look at the code [here](https://github.com/kylestengline/pet-finder-mock-up?files=1). I realize that’s not ideal, but it may take me longer to look for specifics as it’s not fresh in my mind.